# Mautic installed plugin only opening a modal/tooltip and no further actions are being displayed

Tags: mautic

I installed the [MauticCustomImportBundle](https://github.com/mtcextendee/mautic-custom-import-bundle) plugin and after cache refresh it is also visible into the /plugins section but when I am clicking on it, only a modal comes up with no further installations/commands. Its empty.

[image: Only modal]

Where is the problem? Is it with the plugin or the Mautic itself?

Comment: Which mautic version you are using?

Comment: Latest. Not with my Mac at the moment, but it's the fresh and latest version.

Comment: Then it is due to the Mautic version, the plugin is not compatible with the latest Muatic version. That's why this is not work. Just check go for the latest version of the plugin and also check for the compatible Mautic version and if both are same, then it will work perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is supposed to show anything there, I checked the config file of this plugin, there is no entry for integration class, I think the plugin section is supposed to display logo only. You should see additional stuff either in sidebar or on the import page.

Again my deduction is from looking at config file and not trying the plugin. However I see there are forms created and registered so definitely there must be form available somewhere on the system.

Comment: In the last step if **manual installation**: "Setup CustomImport integration". What does this mean? The setup part is done by opening those plugins(as per the videos I watched for plugin installations)

Comment: In that case I think there is something missing in the code in the plugin. I have developed several plugins and the integration has to be registered in the plugin config file. which in this case i don't see(on github).